# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, deployment

**What I'm trying to do:**
I've using Firebase emulator suite until now, and I'm now trying to deploy it.

**Problem:**
I can see my app in the website, but it seems that any action involving Firebase is not working.
[image]

The console error says

```
@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.23.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=unavailable]: The operation could not be completed
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

And here is my `firebase.js`:\

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...,
  authDomain: ...,
  ...
  measurementId: ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
  useFetchStreams: false,
})
// Initialize Analytics and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
connectFirestoreEmulator(db,'0.0.0.0', 8080)
export {
  auth,
  db,
  onAuthStateChanged,
}

export default app;
```

**What I've tried:**

1. I changed my `const db` from

```js
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

to

```js
const db = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
  useFetchStreams: false,
})
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845455/could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times)

2. I changed Firestore rules in Firebase console, to

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904538/firestore-could-not-reach-cloud-firestore-backend-connection-failed-1-times)
**But none of these worked.**

Also, `Running in emulator mode. Do not use with production credentials.` on the bottom of the screen makes me wonder if the app is still running in emulator even though I already ran 'npm run build`and`firebase deploy --only hosting`, and that's causing this error.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the firebase emulator or run your web app locally against production firestore? Are you running in a docker container? Why the `0.0.0.0`? Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0` or `localhost` and launch all the emulators (don't use --only=hosting) and that should allow the app to connect to the firestore emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

1. In `firebase.js`, I had to wrap

```js
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
connectFirestoreEmulator(db,'0.0.0.0', 8080)
```

inside an environment variable:

```js
if (useEmulators) {
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '0.0.0.0', 8080);
}
```

2. Then, I ran `npm install --save-dev cross-env` and updated my `package.json` file:

```
  "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_USE_EMULATORS=true react-scripts start",
  "build": "cross-env REACT_APP_USE_EMULATORS=false react-scripts build",
}
```

3. Finally, I cleaned the build by running `npm run clean`, cleaned the browser cache and then ran `npm run build`.

P.S. I'm not sure if step 1 and 2 were the key, since the error was still there even after then. However, the error was fixed once I went through step 3.